# How can I test my Angular 1.5 controller in my Karma/Mocha test suite?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mocha.js, karma-runner

I'm trying to instantiate my controller in my Mocha test (using Karma as a runner) in order to test some of the controller methods. I'm following something similar to this [Angular ES6 Webpack setup](https://github.com/TheLarkInn/angular-starter-es6-webpack).

Here's what I'm trying:

```
// controller.js

// also, the component that uses this controller
// declares some bindings, like "someData: '<'"

export default class SomeController {
  // notice the injection
  constructor($timeout) {

    // uses ng-annotate
    'ngInject';

  }
}
```

.

```
// test.spec.js (same dir as controller)

import SomeController from './controller.js'

describe('MyComponent', () => {
  let $rootScope;
  let $componentController;
  let $timeout;
  let makeController;

  beforeEach(window.module('app'));

  beforeEach(inject((_$componentController_, _$timeout_) => {
    $componentController = _$componentController_;
    $timeout = _$timeout_;
    makeController = () => {
      // I've tried the 2 options below
      // return new Controller($timeout)
      // return $componentController('myComponent', { $timeout }, { someData: [] });
    };
  }));

  describe('Controller', () => {
    it('does something', () => {

      // FAILS HERE

      $ctrl = makeController();

    });
  });
});
```

So, when I do `new Controller()`, it expects `$timeout` to be passed in as an argument to the constructor (it's supposed to be a dependency injection), and I can't figure out how to pass in `someData` binding.

If I instead try the `$componentController` (as recommended by [Angular 1.5 component docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)), I get this strange error:

```
compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled is not a function
```

So, I looked up this method `$compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled` and tried to set it to both `true` and `false` in my module config, but it still throws saying it's not a function. So I've hit a dead end.

**Any ideas of how I can instantiate my controller to use it for testing?**

Answer (score 6):

Which version of angular are you using ? Went into the same problem and it turned out that I had angular 1.5.7 and angular-mocks 1.5.10.
Put angular-mocks to 1.5.7 (same version of angular) fixed the problem. 
preAssignBindingsEnabled has been added on 1.5.10
eg: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the answer, I'll check that out to see if that's the issue.

Comment: At the end, was it the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to downgrade to angular 1.5.5. Anything higher than that will give you the "TypeError: $compileProvider.preAssignBindingsEnabled is not a function" error.

Also make sure you that you're angular-mocks is the same version(1.5.5).